lstlistings: making backslash an ordinary character
I'm trying to use the listings package to format code in Isabelle/HOL. Fortunately, someone has already done most of the hard work for me by defining the language for the listings package. Unfortunately, Isabelle allows multiple methods of input. When you want to type a "there-exists" symbol (an inverted capital E), there are a bunch of options; one of these is EX, another is \<exists> and a third is \exists. I've got a macro, isi, that lets me format Isabelle code inline, and I'd like to write
The user can type either \isi{EX} or \isi{\exists}, pause briefly, 
and then press TAB to make the `there-exists' character appear. 

in my document. But unfortunately, the backslash before "exists" needs to have another backslash put before it. In the language definition file, I've tried
    alsoletter={<,>,',+,-,.,*,/,=,!,?,:,\$,\%,\_,\&,\~,^,\\},

and
alsoletter={<,>,',+,-,.,*,/,=,!,?,:,\$,\%,\_,\&,\~,^,\},

neither of which works. (The second one causes listings to think that a right-brace is also a letter, and that I've forgotten to close the list, so...things go very wrong.)
Is there a way to prevent this need for an extra backslash?
BTW, the definition of \isi is this:
\newcommand{\isi}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\lstinline[language={Isabelle}]{#1}}}


(While not a perfect match, one of the answers there defines a new command \lsti which you can adapt.)

Thanks ... that did the trick! (And I learned about NewDocumentCommand as well.)
